# Check if pair is group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

On $Q \setminus 0$ is defined operation with $a * b = \frac {ab} 8$. How can I check if $(Q\setminus{0},*)$ is group? Is it commutative and how to find inverse element of $5$? Also how can I prove that $S=\{3^z \vert z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is normal subgroup of $Q$?

Comment: Well, *is it commutative*?? What does that mean in this context? The proof of that statement is either 1 line, or could be shown false with a counterexample.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 primary I want to check if it is a group. How can I do that? Do I need to do all steps from group definition (check association, binary operation etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) For that, you need to check the group axioms. The given set is abviously closed w.r.t. this operation, also it is clearly commutative, since the usual multiplication on $\mathbb{Q}$ is. A unit $e$ should fulfill $a * e = ae/8 = a$, I think you will figure out from that what the unit is. Same thing for inverses: $5'*5 =5'\cdot 5/8=e$, with $5'$ the inverse of 5

2) To show $S$ is a subgroup, you need to show closedness under inversion and the the above group operation; that will need a few calculations. Then, note that in a commutative group, every subgroup is automatically normal (why is this?).

If there are any more problems, just ask in the comments, but I hope that you will fill out the gaps by yourself. Greetings,

Intergalakti

Comment: Good answer, but please avoid using "obviously" as it's a bit condescending.

Comment: I figure out how it's should go. Now only have problem with 2) to show it is commutative

Comment: The commutativity of $(\mathbb{Q},*)$ follows since $a*b=ab/8=ba/8=b*a$

Comment: I found that out, but stuck at (2) with S.